# How to print Tic-Tac-Toe game board?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to print the board for Tic-Tac-Toe game. When I try to run it nothing happens and it says there is invalid syntax. The invalid syntax says that it is some were in my `printboard` function.

I don't see what is wrong with my code.

How can I make it print the board?

```
#Tic-Tac-Toe Game

import os
import time
import random


board = [" " for x in range(10)]

def printTitle():
    print"""

----------------     1 | 2 | 3
TIC - TAC - TOE      4 | 5 | 6
________________     7 | 8 | 9

TO PLAY TIC - TAC - TOE, YOU NEED TO GET THREE IN A ROW.
YOUR CHOICES ARE BETWEEN 1 TO 9.

"""

def printBoard():
    print ( "   |   |   ")
    print (" "+board[1]+" | "+board[2]+" | "+board[3]+"  ")
    print ("   |   |")
    print ("---|---|---")
    print ("   |   |")
    print (" "+board[4]+" | "+board[5]+" | "+board[6]+"  ")
    print ("   |   |")
    print ("---|---|---")
    print ("   |   |")
    print (" "+board[7]+" | "+board[8]+" | "+board[9]+"  ")
    print ("   |   |   ")

while True:
    os.system("clear")
    printTitle()
    printBoard()
    choice = input("Please choose an empty space for X. ").upper()
    choice = int(choice)
    if board[choice] == " ":
        board[choice] = "X"
    else:
        print "Sorry, that space is not empty!"
        time.sleep(1)
```

The result should be:

```
   |   |
   |   |
   |   |
-------------
   |   |
   |   |
   |   |
-------------
   |   |
   |   |
   |   |
```

---

Error message (from @Prune):

```
  File "so.py", line 20
    """
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: It's not "somewhere" -- you get a specific error message with the line number and the text where it happened.  The problem here is that you forgot the parentheses in your `print` command in `printTitle`.

Comment: Post the traceback. @Prune, that print totally works on my machine with python 2.7. His code is probably unaligned.

Comment: @Torxed: not a duplicate -- this is a simple syntax error, not an overall output design.

Comment: I am trying to use python 3 not python 2.7.

Comment: `print` is a _function_ in Python 3, so change the `print"""......"""` to `print("""......""")`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def printTitle():
print"""

----------------     1 | 2 | 3
TIC - TAC - TOE      4 | 5 | 6
________________     7 | 8 | 9

TO PLAY TIC - TAC - TOE, YOU NEED TO GET THREE IN A ROW.
YOUR CHOICES ARE BETWEEN 1 TO 9.

"""
```

Try this :

```
str = '''
        ----------------     1 | 2 | 3
        TIC - TAC - TOE      4 | 5 | 6
        ________________     7 | 8 | 9

        TO PLAY TIC - TAC - TOE, YOU NEED TO GET THREE IN A ROW.
        YOUR CHOICES ARE BETWEEN 1 TO 9.

        '''
 def printTitle(str):
    print(str)
```

There is a problem in your print statement under this function

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the comment quotes in your print statement in `printTitle()` method and not putting string in brackets in last `print` statement. You need to make the changes to your `print` statements:

1. In method `printTitle()`, add remove comment tags and add open brackets as well as backslash(`'\'`) at the end of each line, this is used for representing multi line string.
2. In while loop add the parentheses in your last print statements.

The corrected code is here for your reference.

```
import os
import time
import random


board = [" " for x in range(10)]

def printTitle():
    print("\
\
----------------     1 | 2 | 3\
TIC - TAC - TOE      4 | 5 | 6\
________________     7 | 8 | 9\
\
TO PLAY TIC - TAC - TOE, YOU NEED TO GET THREE IN A ROW.\
YOUR CHOICES ARE BETWEEN 1 TO 9.")


def printBoard():
    print ( "   |   |   ")
    print (" "+board[1]+" | "+board[2]+" | "+board[3]+"  ")
    print ("   |   |")
    print ("---|---|---")
    print ("   |   |")
    print (" "+board[4]+" | "+board[5]+" | "+board[6]+"  ")
    print ("   |   |")
    print ("---|---|---")
    print ("   |   |")
    print (" "+board[7]+" | "+board[8]+" | "+board[9]+"  ")
    print ("   |   |   ")

while True:
    os.system("clear")
    printTitle()
    printBoard()
    choice = input("Please choose an empty space for X. ").upper()
    choice = int(choice)
    if board[choice] == " ":
        board[choice] = "X"
    else:
        print("Sorry, that space is not empty!")
        time.sleep(1)
```